# numpy.linalg.norm gives weird result

Tags: python, numpy

The following gives error:

```
print numpy.linalg.norm(2) # returns 2
print numpy.linalg.norm(2, np.inf) # returns error,
print numpy.linalg.norm(2, np.inf) # returns the same error:

ValueError: Improper number of dimensions to norm.
```

How can I use the above norm with non numpy array input?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [the doc string](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) states:

```
In [165]: np.linalg.norm?
Definition: np.linalg.norm(x, ord=None, axis=None)   
...    
Parameters
----------
x : array_like
    Input array.  If `axis` is None, `x` must be 1-D or 2-D.
```

the first argument to `norm` should be an array_like object. Therefore use

```
In [167]: np.linalg.norm([2], np.inf)
Out[167]: 2
```